# keeping databases secure

Tags: php, mysql, database, security

This isn't about a specific problem I'm having, but I have to clear something up as I have alot at stake with this project.

I'm creating a web application that will deployed to some BIG companies in the UK and if we get this wrong it could cost us hugely!

I need to keep each companies data VERY secure, so what I was wondering is would it be a good idea to create a new database for each organisation, this way their data is totally seperate and if one database is compromised the data for all the organisations wouldn't be effected - this would give us time to react to the security problem before all the data is compromised. My Questions are:

1. What are the short term and long term benefits of this (if any)
2. What are the short term and long term drawbacks of this (if any)
3. Is this good practice?
4. Would it even solve a security issue in the way I anticipate?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use a completely separate server for each company otherwise any compromise of the server will give access to all companies data

Comment: When you say "deployed to", do you mean they will be running it on their servers, or are you offering this as "software as a service"?

Comment: also how many?  if this is a few - maybe dozens - then you can manage pretty well in separate environments...  if hundreds, you will have trouble probably keeping up.

Comment: You should talk with your lawyer about the legal requirements if you handle customer data at large scale. This normally has legal implications.

Comment: My experience is that "BIG companies" dictate their data security requirements to you.

Comment: @hakre we have a lawyer working with us on this, they've informed us that any security compromise could leave us in a vulnerable state. That's why I'm asking how to keep the data as secure as possible.

Comment: As you can never ensure that things will turn out well technically (it's tech), you should already plan for the case of compromise and have that backed up financially. It's less a technical but more an organizional question. If you're a programmer find the person you want to make responsible dealing with that domain (the stakeholeder).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a question about building a "multi-tenanted architecture" for a "software as a service" style application.

The first issue is that separating your databases may or may not be a good idea - but it's not the first question to ask. Someone who can get access to your databases at the level where this matters has already penetrated your application in ways that are hugely damaging - they can almost certainly execute arbitrary commands on your database server. This means that you're not just dealing with damage to one account, but to your entire infrastructure. It's a "lights out" moment, and you have to shut down the whole system whilst you recover.

If they haven't established a shell on your database server, it would mean there's an application-layer security issue - SQL injection, or some way of escalating privileges in your authentication scheme. Again, both are "lights out" moments.

So, make sure all that stuff is totally covered. Include security testing in your development lifecycle; consider using automated penetration testing tools as part of your continuous integration system. Make sure the infrastructure guys harden the whole environment, and consider having a 3rd party security audit when you get close to a release candidate. Consider a code review process focussed on security issues, and agree coding standards with specific security considerations. Tell all your developers about cross site scripting, SQL injection and other application-level vulnerabilities.

Once you've done all that, you've locked the doors and bolted the windows; your database strategy is the equivalent of how you keep the jewelry safe.

Separate databases offer some additional security - but only if you have a corresponding strategy for user management. In most web applications, there are only 2 types of user: "admin" and "web app". "Admin" can create/modify databases (creating databases, tables, views etc.), and can usually also modify data. "Web app" should have only data modification rights, but no rights to modify databases objects.

For splitting the databases to make sense, you must ensure that:

- an attacker who can get access to your web application's file system cannot get access to valid user names and passwords, or if they can, only for one client.
- an attacker can never get access to the "admin" credentials

However, there are other reasons (beyond security) where it makes sense to split up your databases. It reduces the risk of human error, it allows you to scale your system at a more granular level, and it allows you to offer different levels of hosting ("gold" users get their own server, "silver" their own database, "bronze" take their chances).

The big issue you have to solve to make this happen is deployments - how will you deploy new versions of the code, with changes to the database? This in turn may complicate the testing process.

Answer (score 0):

Separate databases, almost certainly. As @Anigel says, perhaps even separate servers, although the management and cost of that is more complex, so will depend on your exact requirements.

- One benefits is that at some point in the future, perhaps one client's data gets bigger, so it's easier to split to a new server, or perhaps they get an upgrade of your platform but another doesn't.
- Backup and restore is easier if you can dump/load whole databases, rather than picking out all the tables with names beginning with **clientX_**.
- Performance measurement will be easier on separate databases.

Just a few quick ideas to get started.

Comment: I agree the cost of separate servers is greater than the cost of a single server. But is the cost of separate servers more than the "cost us hugely!" if they are compromised. Another thing to bear in mind that separate databases are no protection if someone gets on the server, or if the same access details are used for every database

Comment: Hence "will depend on your exact requirements". The cost of dedicated nodes might cheap for them, for example if they're running linux OS on virtualised infrastructure, or *very* expensive if they're running dedicated managed hosted servers at Rackspace.

Answer (score 0):

@Lee Price, Maintaining the separate database for every company will be great thing.

**Advantages:**

- It will keep your database secure
- In long time when the size of the tables are limited to a single company that will give you a drastic performance. The operations will be fast.
- Easy to manipulate the data company wise.
- Help out in terms of support

**Disadvantages:**

- Need to Keep track of the schema change for every company
- Maintain Separate databases
- Maintain separate backups
- Occupy more space as compare to a single database

But i will personally suggest you to go with the separate database for each company.